# Silverlight : What are the config alternatives for silverlight?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

what are the various alternatives to set configuration values for silverlight so that I can modify some settings without recompiling & re deploying silverlight app on the webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass value pairs in the initParams param and these are available in your application Startup event handler StartupEventArgs.

You could also get query paramters from the HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.